# Lvalue conversion of _Generic controlling expression involving array clang warning wrong?

Tags: c, clang

Given the following macro using `_Generic` to determine whether the argument is an array (as opposed to a pointer):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_ARRAY(T)   \
  _Generic( &(T)[0],  \
    typeof(T) : 0,    \
    default   : 1     \
  )

int a[2];
int *p = a;

int main() {
  printf( "IS_ARRAY(a) = %d\n", IS_ARRAY(a) );
  printf( "IS_ARRAY(p) = %d\n", IS_ARRAY(p) );
}
```

and:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 17.0.6
$ clang -std=c2x a.c
```

I get:

```
a.c:15:33: warning: due to lvalue conversion of the controlling expression, association of type 'typeof ((a))' (aka 'int[2]') will never be selected because it is of array type [-Wunreachable-code-generic-assoc]
   15 |   printf( "IS_ARRAY(a) = %d\n", IS_ARRAY(a) );
      |                                 ^
a.c:7:5: note: expanded from macro 'IS_ARRAY'
    7 |     typeof( (T) ) : 0,                                                      \
      |     ^
1 warning generated.
```

Yet:

```
$ ./a.out
IS_ARRAY(a) = 1
IS_ARRAY(p) = 0
```

appears to work despite the warning. Is the warning wrong here?

Comment: Note that `typeof` is not, as of C18, part of standard C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I added the missing `-std=c2x`. It gives the same warning either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it means is that the first expression of `_Generic` is converted as per "lvalue conversion" (new change in C17) and the generic association list following is examined against the converted value.

This was because in C11 it was ambiguous how to treat qualifiers inside `_Generic`. Some compilers allowed types + qualifiers `const int: 1, int: 2` etc as two separate cases but some didn't. So as a fix, C17 guarantees a lvalue conversion of the passed expression, so it can never become `const int` in my example. Note how clang gives the same warning as you got if we attempt this:

```
#define IS_INT(x) _Generic((x), int: 1, const int: 1)
```

Nor can it become an array type for that matter, since arrays cannot be assigned/lvalue converted. The warning you get is for `typeof(T)` which is an array type.

- `(&T)[0]` is not a correct fix because this will turn the array into a pointer, then into an array again, and then it will decay... and you get a `int*`.
- `&(T)[0]` is not a correct fix because this will derefence the array, type `int`, then you get an address of that, `int*`.

Note precedence `[]` over unary `&`.

---

What you can do however, is to take the address of the passed expression and check if it is a pointer to array.

And as another little trick, the type `int (*)[]` (pointer to array of incomplete type) is compatible with every array pointer `int (*)[n]` no matter `n` (see "composite types" C17 6.2.7).

Fixed code, C23 conforming:

```
#define IS_ARRAY(T)            \
  _Generic( &(T),              \
    typeof(*T) (*)[]  : true,  \
    default           : false  \
  )
```

- If we are to pass an `int a[2];` to this, then the array doesn't get "decayed" into a pointer to the first element but rather `&(T)` turns it to `int (*)[2]`.
- `typeof(*T)` does however decay the array as usual and we end up with `int`.
- `int (*)[2]` is compatible with `int (*)[]` so it was an array and with the correct element type.

Comment: I like the idea of taking the address of the macro argument so as to get a pointer to an array where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is correct, and the macro is working as intended.

As the warning states, it's not possible for an array type to match a specific generic selection case.  However, you're exploiting that fact by way of the `default` case you've put in place, so what you have it fine.

You can add the `-Wno-unreachable-code-generic-assoc` option to clang to explicitly disable this warning.

Comment: Had the controlling expression been _just_ `(T)`, then your answer makes sense. But as at attempt to work around the conversion is why I made the expression be `&(T)[0]` instead, i.e., a pointer. So if the type is a pointer, why is it still warning?

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas The warning isn't looking at the controlling expression but at the specific case.  It's telling you that that case is impossible to be selected.  Notice that you're only getting the warning on `IS_ARRAY(a)` and not on `IS_ARRAY(p)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the warning wrong here?

With respect to `typeof` as it will be specified by the next version of the C language spec, due Real Soon Now, a `typeof` operation is among the contexts in which an lvalue of array type is not automatically converted to a pointer.  The `typeof` an array is the operand's actual (array) type, not the type of the pointer to which the operand would automatically be converted in most other contexts.

On the other hand, wherever the expression `&(T)[0]` is valid at all, its type is definitely a pointer type.  That includes in particular when `T` has array type.  **The warning is correct**: when the macro argument has array type, the first alternative of the generic selection will not be exercised.  **But that just means your macro works as intended!**

This seems a bit of a weird warning to issue, however, because it is normal that only one alternative of any given generic selection expression will be selected.  But there is nevertheless a bit of a point, in that a `typeof` selector such as you are using can never match the controlling expression of a generic selection when its operand is an array, because the controlling expression *is* subject to automatic conversion of arrays to pointers.