# Using _Generic to implement IS_POINTER(p) with rvalue in C23?

Tags: c, c23

I want to implement `IS_POINTER(P)` using `_Generic`. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881417/99089) that implements `IS_ARRAY(A)` as a starting point, I have:

```c
#define IS_POINTER(P)   \
  _Generic( &(P),       \
    typeof(*P) ** : 1,  \
    default       : 0   \
  )
```

Given:

```c
int a[1];
int *p;

int main() {
  printf( "IS_POINTER(a) = %d\n", IS_POINTER(a) );
  printf( "IS_POINTER(p) = %d\n", IS_POINTER(p) );
}
```

I get:

```
$ gcc -std=c2x is_pointer.c && ./a.out
IS_POINTER(a) = 0
IS_POINTER(p) = 1
```

which is correct. However, if I instead do:

```c
int i;

int main() {
  printf( "IS_POINTER(&i) = %d\n", IS_POINTER(&i) );
}
```

i.e., take the address of an object using `&` to yield a pointer, I get:

```
is_pointer.c:5:36: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int *'
  printf( "IS_POINTER(&i) = %d\n", IS_POINTER(&i) );
                                   ^          ~~
is_pointer.c:5:13: note: expanded from macro 'IS_POINTER'
  _Generic( &(P),           \
            ^ ~
1 error generated.
```

I understand that you can't take the address of an rvalue, i.e., `&(&i)`. My question is: is there a way to rewrite `IS_POINTER()` to make it *also* work in cases where you explicitly take the address via `&` of an object and pass *that* to `IS_POINTER()`?

I've been kicking it around and haven't come up with a way.

Comment: I do not think it is possible

Comment: It looks like a XY problem to me.

Comment: @gulpr It's not an XY problem. I want a C equivalent to the C++ `std::is_pointer`. I want _that_ so I can do `static_assert()` on macro parameters for those that require pointers.

Comment: It is not possible in C.

Comment: The solution depends on if you want to use this on any type or just to distinguish between pointers and arrays. The latter is easy, just wrap the first argument of _Generic inside a compound literal.

Comment: *"I want a C equivalent to the C++ std::is_pointer."* ¿Why don't you use C++ then?

Comment: @user7860670 Because the entire rest of the existing codebase is in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your macro to make the passed argument a compound literal (which is an lvalue), to cover the `&i` scenario.

```
#define IS_POINTER(P)            \
  _Generic( &(typeof(P)){0},     \
    typeof(*P)**  : 1,           \
    default       : 0            \
  )
```

However, this macro will still not work for plain variables which aren't pointers, because then `typeof(*P)` is a syntax error. I'm not aware of a way to distinguish between plain variables and pointers in standard C. There are some non-standard extensions you can use: [Check if a macro argument is a pointer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255148/check-if-a-macro-argument-is-a-pointer-or-not)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of those... am hoping to do this in standard C.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `&(P)` used in control variable of `_Generic` with a compound literal (CL). The CLs are l-values so their address can be taken.

Basically replace:

```
_Generic( &(P), ... )
```

with:

```
_Generic( &(typeof(P)){0}, ... )
```

It should work fine. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/faf717v11).

Comment: It's better, but, as @Lundin points out, it doesn't compile if you pass a plain `int` variable rather than print `0`.